# CKeditor integration with Alfresco trouble

Tags: alfresco

I install ckeditor and configuration file how it is describe [there](https://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/CKEditorFormControl) .

but when I try to edit or create HTML file in alfresco , the content area is empty (blank) and I can't edit anything. What is the problem ??
 Help please!:(

Comment: project home is on github: https://github.com/share-extras/ckeditor-forms - take care to use the latest version - there are also several pull request that seem to fix some issues related to alfresco 4: https://github.com/share-extras/ckeditor-forms/pulls

If it is still not working, then try to describe your problem in more detail (e.g. Alfresco version, browser ...) and open an issue in the github project.

Answer (score -1):

What I did: 
1) I downloaded ckeditor-forms-master from github 
2) In cmd from parent folder ckeditor-forms-master I execute these commands 
ant clean dist-jar 
ant -Dtomcat.home=C:/Alfresco/tomcat clean dist-jar hotcopy-tomcat-jar
Both were successfully executed.

Restarted the alfresco tomcat server. Now when I create/edit HTML file the context area is blank...
alfresco version 4.2.f.
browser google chrome

Comment: did you take a look at 4.x pull-requests?: https://github.com/share-extras/ckeditor-forms/pulls - e.g. https://github.com/share-extras/ckeditor-forms/pull/4

Comment: Yes I did all changes in these files and rebuild project with ant, next I install ckeditor, the problem wasn't solved:(